# How to obtain data from collection in firestore with where clause?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to obtain data (langtitude field) from collection in firestore, with where clause, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = db.collection(collection).whereGreaterThan("longtitude", String.valueOf(bounds.northeast.latitude));
query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }

                if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, queryDocumentSnapshots.getMetadata().toString());        
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
                }
            }
        });
```

I only get

```
SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false}
```

But I want fields from collection. How to do it?

I tried different methods and none of them returned a fields in a collection.

Comment: What other methods have you tried? Please provide some examples.

Comment: What is the value of `bounds.northeast.latitude`? Please also add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a query against a collection, you get a `QuerySnapshot` which can contain zero or more documents. To get the actual documents, you'll need to loop over the documents as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection):

```
public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
        return;
    }

    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        if (doc.get("longtitude") != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, doc.getString("longtitude"));
        }
    }
}
```